# How to load all the gmail contacts in my iOS app either through OAuth or any other open source?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, gmail-api, google-contacts-api

I want to show the name and their email ids in a list view . These are basically all the gmail contacts of my particular logged in account.

I have successfully implemented the Gmail OAuth APIs in order to get the client login, but not getting the way to access all my gmail contacts.

Any reference link will be appreciated.

Comment: For retrieving all the contacts using contacts API, you can send request https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full where userEmail is the value of the email to which you want to retrieve contacts. check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ and https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Comment: @SGC, can i check directly as like `Facebook API console` without integration. just for checking purpose.

Comment: @SGC, is there any google api console available where i can check directly without integration.

Comment: Google has an APIs explorer site but it does not support the Contacts API.

Comment: @abraham, so that means i can not checked directly. so only way to checked by integrating. right?

Comment: The Contacts API is just an HTTP API so you can try it out with curl or any other rest/HTTP client.